# Android List header view need scroller

Tags: android, listview

I have a listview with a header that does not feet the screen. If the list have many item that its fine, because I can scroll down. But in some cases my listview is empty. So I can't scroll.

Any ideas about what can I do?

Comment: I can't imagine such header. Why don't you use empty view for empty ListView?

Comment: @dimetil it's not empty it has a header. But yeah its probably the solution. Its just a bit complicated, I was hoping that there could be some thing simpler.